# Logical circuits functions and designing vhdl code

Tags: vhdl

I don't know if those 2 functions i have found using Karnaugh tables are mathcing the VHDL code below (I am not really good at VHDL).

The functions :

**f <= (x3 or x5) and (x2 or x4') and (x4' or x5) and (x1' or x2) and (x2' or x4 or x5')**

and

**g <= (x2 or x4' or x5') and (x2 or x3' or x4') and (x2' or x4 or x5') and (x1' or x2 or x5') and (x1 or x3' or x4' or x5')**

Here is the code:

**basic_components.vhd** :

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
package basic_components is
  -- AND2 declaration
 component myAND2
        port (in1, in2: in std_logic; out1: out std_logic);
 end component;
 -- OR2 declaration
  component myOR2
       port (in1, in2: in std_logic; out1: out std_logic);
 end component;
  --NOT1 declaration
  component myNOT1           
       port (in1: in std_logic; out1: out std_logic);
 end component;
end package basic_components;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

 -- 2 input AND gate
 entity myAND2 is

       port (in1, in2: in std_logic; out1: out std_logic);
 end myAND2;
 architecture model_conc of myAND2 is
       begin

                 out1 <= in1 and in2;
 end model_conc;
  -- 2 input OR gate
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
  entity myOR2 is

       port (in1, in2: in std_logic; out1: out std_logic);
 end myOR2;
 architecture model_conc2 of myOR2 is
       begin

                 out1 <= in1 or in2;
 end model_conc2;
  -- 1 input NOT gate
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
  entity myNOT1 is

       port (in1: in std_logic; out1: out std_logic);
 end myNOT1;
 architecture model_conc3 of myNOT1 is
       begin

                 out1 <= not in1;
 end model_conc3;
```

**problem1.vhd**:

```
    library ieee, basic_components;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use work.basic_components.all;
entity Problem1 is
    port (x1, x2, x3,x4,x5: in std_logic;
    f,g: out std_logic);
end Problem1;

architecture structural of Problem1 is
signal not_x1,not_x2,not_x3,not_x4,not_x5,pos1,pos2,pos3,pos4,pos5,pos6,pos7,pos8,pos9: std_logic;

begin

I0: myNOT1 port map(x1,not_x1);
I1: myNOT1 port map(x2,not_x2);
I2: myNOT1 port map(x3,not_x3);
I3: myNOT1 port map(x4,not_x4);
I4: myNOT1 port map(x5,not_x5);
I5: myOR2 port map(x2,not_x4,pos1);
I6: myOR2 port map(x3,x5,pos2);
I7: myOR2 port map(not_x4,x5,pos3);
I8: myOR2 port map(not_x1,x2,pos4);
I9: myOR3 port map(not_x2,x4,not_x5,pos5);
I10: myOR3 port map(not_x2,not_x4,not_x5,pos6);
I11: myOR3 port map(x2,not_x3,not_x4,pos7);
I12: myOR3 port map(not_x1,x2,not_x5,pos8);
I13: myOR4 port map(not_x1,not_x3,not_x4,x5,pos9);
I14: myAND5 port map(pos1,pos2,pos3,pos4,pos5,f);
I15:myAND5 port map(pos5,pos6,pos7,pos8,pos9,g);

end structural;
```

Comment: Why don't you write `f <= (x3 or x5) and (x2 or x4) ...` etc.? Then it would be trivial to check if the code matches the formula. The `basic_components` are pretty useless if they only wrap the built-in operators, and only obfuscate the code.

Comment: Unfortunately they teach VHDL code in school like this which IMHO is pretty dumb. Because I've seen people who are supposedly experienced do this crap code because they were never corrected in a professional setting.

Comment: Your bold expressions with apostrophes apparently meaning logical negation match those found in grorel's answer (to an unstated problem) for f1 and g1. "*I don't know if those 2 functions i have found using Karnaugh tables are mathcing the VHDL code below ...", can you ask a specific question?

Comment: You don't supply entity and architecture pairs nor component declarations for all your primitives (myOR3, myOR5, myAND5). It's not possible for a second party to verify your implementation matches the bold expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments in your post say, this way of writing VHDL is not "practical". But you can write your equations in a better way and compile/simulate both results at the same time to compare.

```
library ieee, basic_components;
  use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
  use work.basic_components.all;

entity Problem1 is
    port (x1, x2, x3,x4,x5: in std_logic;
    f,g: out std_logic);
end Problem1;

architecture structural of Problem1 is
signal not_x1,not_x2,not_x3,not_x4,not_x5,pos1,pos2,pos3,pos4,pos5,pos6,pos7,pos8,pos9,f1,f2,g1,g2: std_logic;

begin
-- First equations the way VHDL is meaned to be used
f1 <= (x3 or x5) and (x2 or not x4) and (not x4 or x5) and (not x1 or x2) and (not x2 or x4 or not x5);
g1 <= (x2 or not x4 or not x5) and (x2 or not x3 or not x4) and (not x2 or x4 or not x5) and (not x1 or x2 or not x5) and (x1 or not x3 or not x4 or not x5);

-- Second equations, your school problem
I0: myNOT1 port map(x1,not_x1);
I1: myNOT1 port map(x2,not_x2);
I2: myNOT1 port map(x3,not_x3);
I3: myNOT1 port map(x4,not_x4);
I4: myNOT1 port map(x5,not_x5);
I5: myOR2 port map(x2,not_x4,pos1);
I6: myOR2 port map(x3,x5,pos2);
I7: myOR2 port map(not_x4,x5,pos3);
I8: myOR2 port map(not_x1,x2,pos4);
I9: myOR3 port map(not_x2,x4,not_x5,pos5);
I10: myOR3 port map(not_x2,not_x4,not_x5,pos6);
I11: myOR3 port map(x2,not_x3,not_x4,pos7);
I12: myOR3 port map(not_x1,x2,not_x5,pos8);
I13: myOR4 port map(not_x1,not_x3,not_x4,x5,pos9);
I14: myAND5 port map(pos1,pos2,pos3,pos4,pos5,f2);  -- Here, f is replaced by f2 
I15:myAND5 port map(pos5,pos6,pos7,pos8,pos9,g2);  -- Here, g is replaced by g2 

-- process for auto-test
process(f1,f2,g1,g2)
begin
  -- this will test the equation f1=f2, if wrong the simulator will stop with the message "F calcul is wrong"
  assert (f1 = f2) report "F calcul is wrong" severity failure;
  -- this will test the equation g1=g2, if wrong the simulator will stop with the message "G calcul is wrong"
  assert (g1 = g2) report "G calcul is wrong" severity failure;
end process;

-- output is linked to your school solution
f <= f2;
g <= g2;

end architecture;
```

Now you have to write a testbench to give the 32 possible inputs to your entity and see if the simulator complains about anything.

Comment: You're missing an end statement for the architecture body.

Comment: @user1155120 : totally agree ! That's how to make mistake writing code directly on SO. :s